# add last function using deque with data classes

Tags: python, deque

Hi I'm trying to solve this code but not really making any headway. I'm supposed to fix a code by adding code to the class, but I haven't worked with deque before and can't really grasp how to do it.

the main.py looks like this

```
import Deque as deq


empty = deq.Deque()    
deque = deq.Deque() 

for i in range(1, 11):
    deque.add_last(i)
print(deque.to_string())
print("Size:", deque.size)
```

and this is the class

```
@dataclass
class Node:
value: int = None
nxt: Any = None 


  @dataclass
  class Deque:
  head: Node = None      # First node in queue
  tail: Node = None      # Last node in queue
  size: int = 0


  # Add element n as last entry in deque
  def add_last(self, n):
```

and the output is supposed to look like this

```
{ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 }
Size: 10
```

but the thing is that I don't really know how to use deque, so I would really appreciate the help with helping me solve the add_last function.

Comment: The second code snippet needs fix of the indentation. The "Node" class is not suitable for a deque as it only supports a singly linked list while a deque should be implemented as a doubly linked list (or use a completely different approach). Where is this code from?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Add element n as last entry in deque
def add_last(self, n):
    # Case where the deque is empty.
    if self.head == None and self.tail == None:
        self.head = Node(n, None)
        self.tail = self.head
    else:
        # Case where the deque is not empty.
        self.tail.nxt = Node(n, None)
        self.tail = self.tail.nxt

    self.size += 1
```

For more info I would research linked lists and also refer to the python dataclass documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not printing anything. The output ends up being "None
Size: 0" instead of { 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 }
Size: 10. I'm thinking it might haft to do with to.string class which I wrote like this      def to_string(self):
          s = "{ "
          node = self.head
          while node is not None:
                s += str(node.val) + " "
                node = node.nxt
          s += "}"
          return s